# Upload Image and parameters from android(retrofit) to django get bad request

Tags: android, django, retrofit

I use API like this ;

```
@POST("api/info/save")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadMultiFile(@Body RequestBody file);
```

and this function get images from an arraylist and add parameters to send server;

```
private void uploadMultiFile(final String event_date, final int event_type, final int coordinate_x, final int coordinate_y) {

        String url = Constant.baseUrl;

        Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate();
        coordinate.setX(coordinate_x);
        coordinate.setY(coordinate_y);

        TokenInterceptor interceptor=new TokenInterceptor();
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(client)
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        Api service = retrofit.create(Api .class);

        MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
        builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);

        builder.addFormDataPart("event_date", event_date);
        builder.addFormDataPart("event_type", String.valueOf(event_type));
        builder.addFormDataPart("coordinate", String.valueOf(coordinate));
        

        // Map is used to multipart the file using okhttp3.RequestBody
        // Multiple Images
        for (int i = 0; i < imagePathList.size(); i++) {
            File file = new File(imagePathList.get(i));
            builder.addFormDataPart("image[]", file.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file));
        }

        MultipartBody requestBody = builder.build();
        Call<ResponseBody> call = service.uploadMultiFile(requestBody);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                Toast.makeText(MMEActivity.this, "Success " + response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

                Log.d("d", "Error " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });


    }
```

I got Bad Request Error. How can ı solve this problem? I use Django in my backend. This my function to get images and parameters from request.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def eventInfoSave(request):
    event_date = request.data['event_date']
    print(request.data)
    .
    .
    if bool(request.FILES.getlist('image', False)) == True:
       uploaded_file = request.FILES.getlist('image')
```

When ı use postman there is not any problem. I can get all images from single key.

Comment: What's the exception/error in the backend?

Comment: @bdbd ı got code=400 Bad Request when use this. Also request not arrived django. When ı added  @Headers("Content-Type: application/json") request arrived but give; [size=105 text={"detail":"JSON parse error - 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x…]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the my problem using;

```
@Multipart
    @POST("/save")
    Call<Response> uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part[] image, @Part("event_date") RequestBody event_date,
                                       @Part("event_type") RequestBody event_type,
.
.
.);
```

I change my function to;

```
private void uploadMultiFile(final String event_date, final int event_type, final int coordinate_x, final int coordinate_y) {

String url = Constant.baseUrl;

        Coordinate coordinate_ = new Coordinate();
        coordinate_.setX(coordinate_x);
        coordinate_.setY(coordinate_y);
        String coordinate__ = new Gson().toJson(coordinate_);

        TokenInterceptor interceptor=new TokenInterceptor();
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(client)
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        Api service = retrofit.create(Api .class);

        MultipartBody.Part[] surveyImagesParts = new MultipartBody.Part[imagePathList.size()];

        for (int index = 0; index <
                imagePathList.size(); index++) {
            Log.d("ss",
                    "requestUploadSurvey: survey image " +
                            index +
                            "  " +imagePathList.get(index));
            File file = new File(imagePathList.get(index));
            RequestBody imageBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"),
                    file);
            surveyImagesParts[index] = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image",
                    file.getName(),
                    imageBody);
        }

        RequestBody event_date= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),
                event_date_);
.
.
.



        Call<LocationResponse> call = service.uploadImage(surveyImagesParts,event_date,....);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<LocationResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LocationResponse> call, Response<LocationResponse> response) {

                if(response.body() != null)
                {
                    displayAlert(MyApp.getContext().getString(R.string.notification_successful_text),MyApp.getContext().getString(R.string.upload_photo_successful_text));

                } else {

                    

                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LocationResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                
            }
        });


    }
```